# Trouble using XSLT variables to hold attributes

Tags: xslt, variables

In my xslt template I am having a `for-each` statement. In that `for-each` I am making different conditions. I want to have there a variable of string type which shall contain class attributes that will be assigned to a `<li>`.

As I am new to xslt please provide me some examples or how can I achieve what I want to do.

Here is a bit of my code so you can see what I am taking about:

```
<xsl:if test="count($currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; '0'">
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
        <li><xsl:attribute name="class">
                topNavigLi
                page<xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
                <xsl:if test="@nodeName='Network' ">
                    has_submenu network
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    current topNavigLi
                    page<xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    last topNavigLi
                    page<xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id and position() = last()">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    current last topNavigLi
                    page<xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
```

It would be much elegant to have a variable and than **concatenate** to it while doing tests.
I have tried like this but returns nothing.

```
<xsl:variable name="li_class" select="page"> </xsl:variable>

<xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:value-of select="li_class" /> 
</xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: That makes almost no sense. Please, edit the question and provide a complete, but small and clear example: 1. Source XML document; 2. Wanted result (only related to the problem); 3. Explanation of the requirements that the transformation must implement.

Comment: OK, I think I understood the question, and even provided an answer -- however, do try to express your problems in a clear way.

Comment: Just to emphasize what Dimitre says: expecting us to reverse engineer your requirements from code that doesn't work (and is fundamentally wrong) is expecting rather a lot.

Comment: I'd like to see this title change.  This is not a general "How to use variables in XSLT" post: it pertains only to a specific problem. Unfortunately, google hasn't realized that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading in the meanwhile I found out(something that however I knew, mostly) that:

> The fact that you need to modify an  shows that you are
>   not thinking in XSLT.
>
> XSLT is a functional programming language, which, among other things
>   means that there is no way one can change a variable. Variables in a
>   functional programming language by definition are immutable.
>   Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/xmlandnetfx/thread/2bf7d238-92d2-4453-a683-4bfb0c667795

So I have changed my logic a little:
I put all conditions within xsl attribute like this:

```
 <xsl:if test="count($currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']) &gt; '0'">
            <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
                <li>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
                        page topNavigLi page<xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
                        <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">
                            current 
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                            last
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@nodeName='Network' ">
                            has_submenu network
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
```

So no need of extra temp var.

Comment: XSLT is NOT a functional language!

Answer (score 8):

**Here is an example doing what I think you are asking for:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="num">
  <xsl:variable name="vResult">

    <xsl:if test=". mod 2 = 0">Even </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test=". mod 3 = 0"> mult3</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(. mod 2 = 0 or . mod 3 = 0)">none</xsl:if>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vnormResults" select="normalize-space($vResult)"/>

  <num tests="{$vnormResults}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </num>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the result is**:

```
<nums>
   <num tests="none">01</num>
   <num tests="Even">02</num>
   <num tests="mult3">03</num>
   <num tests="Even">04</num>
   <num tests="none">05</num>
   <num tests="Even mult3">06</num>
   <num tests="none">07</num>
   <num tests="Even">08</num>
   <num tests="mult3">09</num>
   <num tests="Even">10</num>
</nums>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want to put the string like 'page1' in a variable and re-use?

If so, try...

```
           <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::* [@level=$level]/[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
                <xsl:variable name="page-num" select="concat('page',position())" /> 
                <li><xsl:attribute name="class">
                        topNavigLi
                        <xsl:value-of select="$page-num" />
                        <xsl:if test="@nodeName='Network' ">
                            has_submenu network
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
                            current topNavigLi
                            <xsl:value-of select="$page-num" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
                            last topNavigLi
                            page<xsl:number value="position()" format="1" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="@id = $currentPage/@id and position() = last()">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
                            current last topNavigLi
                            <xsl:value-of select="$page-num" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
```

In XSLT 1.0, the syntax for defining variables is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#variables) an for XSLT 2.0 it is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#variables-and-parameters). To access the variables within an XPATH context, precede the name with a dollar sign ($).

Answer (score 2):

Get the value of variables in XSLT like so (with the `$` sign):

```
<xsl:variable name="li_class" select="page"> </xsl:variable>

<xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:value-of select="$li_class" /> 
</xsl:attribute>
```